# Can magic cause others to ignore me?

Tags: sihr

I have always been good; when others have wronged me I forgave them and generally get along very well with people, but now they have again started ignoring me for no reason.  This is giving me a hard time because at home everyone around is either rude or they only talk when they need me. It is the same thing happening to me on certain sites that I use, users there treat me same way.

I have turned to Allah but I want to know:

**Can magic cause someone to ignore you?**

Comment: I don't know about your life but on website it not like that everyone is ignoring they have not a reason to talk to you find a topic and then they will help you.

Comment: I tell you my problem i can speak or write proper English that why no one talk to me.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that this is not a site for peer support or advise on personal problems. So your questions will be soon closed by moderators. But we can discuss your problem in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17209594#17209594). I leave a message there for you to read. I hope it helps you.

Comment: but as for your last question, magic can be effective only and only in case we are weak and vulnerable towards the influences of Satan. Otherwise magic and magicians can not exert influence over us as a believer is protected by Allah and His angels.

Comment: @infatuated Sorry but I would have to disagree with you. Allah SWT tests his servants however He wants. Even Rusullulah SAW was affected, not because he SAW was weak but because Allah SWT wanted to tell us, the ummah to what to do in such situations. Please have a look at my answer if you have disagreements. Jazakummlahu khairan, wassalam

Comment: Of course I reckon you'd better to notice some other points as well(to solve your problem) which are shown in below:

Initially, we can not always consider each matter as magic, sometimes accidentally ...

secondly, you'd better pay attention to your behaviour with more care, perhaps there is a problem from you that ... (Of course just as a likelihood..)

Answer (score 1):

> Can magic cause someone to ignore you?

No, it cannot. Some people refer to the following Ayah:

[image]

> And they followed [instead] what the devils had recited during the reign of Solomon. It was not Solomon who disbelieved, but the devils disbelieved, teaching people magic and that which was revealed to the two angels at Babylon, Harut and Marut. But the two angels do not teach anyone unless they say, "We are a trial, so do not disbelieve [by practicing magic]." And [yet] they learn from them that by which they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm anyone through it except by permission of Allah. And the people learn what harms them and does not benefit them. But the Children of Israel certainly knew that whoever purchased the magic would not have in the Hereafter any share. And wretched is that for which they sold themselves, if they only knew. [2:102]

As a proof that Magic can be used to separate between a Husband and a Wife, so other things are much easier. What they don't understand is that the Ayah does not speak about Magic in that case, but rather about learning [things like](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=61&ID=143):

- Deception/lying to make a spouse hate one another
- Using medical applications to make someone's mind go crazy until his spouse leaves
- Using tricky, etc.

The only [hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/58/17) that was reported during the time of the prophet and his companions about "magic" was the prophet getting sick in his mind by someone and Allah cures him, a Hadith which in my opinion is weak/invalid.

If magic could indeed do things out of the norm, you would have seen its application widely spread in modern countries, where people can become millionaires in such tricky.

I advise you and the one you are afraid of leaving you to read quran and pray on time and nothing shall happen inshala.

Answer (score 1):

Everything has a cause. Believing in magic guides you to an unreasonable world. Don't loss your logic. What the hell is magic. Ignore all these subjects and have a good life and good time. If something happen to you, it's because of yourself or others. Sometimes being not too careful about our behaviors, will change other behaviors about us. Sometimes gossips about you will change other behaviors. Ask them and they will tell you. All in a reasonable way, dude.

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu `alaiykum,

Magic can cause a lot of harm but often people (even our Muslim brothers/sisters) miss a point, `Without permission of Allah (Subhaanahu wa ta'ala) nothing can harm you what so ever`.

I have always been a person of references so here it is

> And they followed [instead] what the devils had recited during the
>   reign of Solomon. It was not Solomon who disbelieved, but the devils
>   disbelieved, teaching people magic and that which was revealed to the
>   two angels at Babylon, Harut and Marut. But the two angels do not
>   teach anyone unless they say, "We are a trial, so do not disbelieve
>   [by practicing magic]." And [yet] they learn from them that by which
>   **they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm
>   anyone through it except by permission of Allah**. And the people learn
>   what harms them and does not benefit them. But the Children of Israel
>   certainly knew that whoever purchased the magic would not have in the
>   Hereafter any share. And wretched is that for which they sold
>   themselves, if they only knew. [Al-Baqara 2:102](http://muflihun.com/2/102)

So my dear brother/sister in Islam, even if you are under spell of magic, nothing to worry about. Allah (SWT) has given us cure.
Remember, there are possibilities where you are not under the spell, unfortunately people tend to think more that they are under spell of magic. So try looking at other things too before you conclude. That being said, there is nothing wrong with performing ruqtah over yourself (continue read to find what ruqya means)

I would highly recommend any one interested in how magic works and it's cure in Islam to read [Reality of magic and its cure in Islam](http://rc.muflihun-contents.com/magic.pdf) that I wrote when I was researching this vast topic of interest. I will tell you what I have told every one I shared this document with, do not read one part and skip other, read word to word. In-sha'-Allah, this will be of great benefit for you.
This document explains what ruqyah is.

Wassalam wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu

Answer (score -2):

**First of all I ought to mention that it could be feasible that everything be happened by magic. Even such as the issue which you mentioned "can magic cause someone to ignore you ...**

Secondly, the verse below (Surah al-Baqarah: 102) could be helpful for you to read it as a related issue regarding magic.

> وَاتَّبَعُوا مَا تَتْلُو الشَّيَاطِينُ عَلَىٰ مُلْكِ سُلَيْمَانَ ۖ
>   وَمَا كَفَرَ سُلَيْمَانُ وَلَـٰكِنَّ الشَّيَاطِينَ كَفَرُوا
>   يُعَلِّمُونَ النَّاسَ السِّحْرَ وَمَا أُنزِلَ عَلَى الْمَلَكَيْنِ
>   بِبَابِلَ هَارُوتَ وَمَارُوتَ ۚ وَمَا يُعَلِّمَانِ مِنْ أَحَدٍ حَتَّىٰ
>   يَقُولَا إِنَّمَا نَحْنُ فِتْنَةٌ فَلَا تَكْفُرْ ۖ فَيَتَعَلَّمُونَ
>   مِنْهُمَا مَا يُفَرِّقُونَ بِهِ بَيْنَ الْمَرْءِ وَزَوْجِهِ ۚ وَمَا
>   هُم بِضَارِّينَ بِهِ مِنْ أَحَدٍ إِلَّا بِإِذْنِ اللَّـهِ ۚ
>   وَيَتَعَلَّمُونَ مَا يَضُرُّهُمْ وَلَا يَنفَعُهُمْ ۚ وَلَقَدْ عَلِمُوا
>   لَمَنِ اشْتَرَاهُ مَا لَهُ فِي الْآخِرَةِ مِنْ خَلَاقٍ ۚ وَلَبِئْسَ
>   مَا شَرَوْا بِهِ أَنفُسَهُمْ ۚ لَوْ كَانُوا يَعْلَمُونَ ﴿١٠٢﴾
>
> And they followed [instead] what the devils had recited during the
>   reign of Solomon. It was not Solomon who disbelieved, but the devils
>   disbelieved, teaching people magic and that which was revealed to the
>   two angels at Babylon, Harut and Marut. But the two angels do not
>   teach anyone unless they say, "We are a trial, so do not disbelieve
>   [by practicing magic]." And [yet] they learn from them that by which
>   they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm
>   anyone through it except by permission of Allah. And the people learn
>   what harms them and does not benefit them. But the Children of Israel
>   certainly knew that whoever purchased the magic would not have in the
>   Hereafter any share. And wretched is that for which they sold
>   themselves, if they only knew.
>
> (2:102)

**Therefore,** it is seen that Magic is considered as an actual issue, then it could be the cause of many matter such as the matter which you mentioned if it make you be ignored by someone. So you can remove its bad effect by trusting to Allah and reciting some duas ... such as La-hawla-wa-la-qowwata-ell=a-bellah-al-aliel-azim (لاحول و لاقوه الا بالله العلی العظیم) and so forth.

---

**Source**:

- [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/2:102)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, black magic can make others ignore you and even hate you. Why it has happened to me for the past years and it’s still happening. You should find a raqi ( someone who performs Ruqya) and who follows the Sunnah. Don’t go to anyone who say they know how to do ruqya when they ask for your mother’s name, if they have weird symbols on paper, hanged on the waklls etc, and especially if they whisper something that is not from the Qu’ran. These are real magicians and they work alongside with the demons from the jinns. Sihr is very powerful and can even cause death. Stay strong and always turn to Allah for help. Salaam.